# how to upload a file using autoit in protractor

Tags: file-upload, jasmine, protractor, autoit

I tried the code below but it isn't working. Can someone help me understand how to upload a file using `autoit` in protractor?

```
    var path = require('path');
    var file = "../Snaptrude/plans/"+filepath+"";
    console.log('file path',file)
    var filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, file);
   // browser.sleep(3000);
    element(by.css('input[type="file"]')).sendKeys(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

`var path = require('path');
var appRoot = require('app-root-path');
var uploadFile = appRoot + '/path of the file which you want to upload';`
`var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
        var control = element(by.xpath('you need to take the xpath of uploaded file'));
        control.getText().then(function(text) {
            if (text == 'filename') {`
enter code here`console.log("success");
  }`

without using autoit you can upload the file using above way, if you are work on any web application.

Comment: Hi Chetan, which code I have to place inside the if block. can you send me the entire code for file upload